# C# login system from text file error

Tags: c#, authentication, text-files

Okay I'm new to coding and I know a login in SQL is more secure and all, but for this is just for learning streamwriter and reader.

```
namespace text_file_login
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void btn_register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StreamWriter user_reg = new StreamWriter(@"E:\SSD\Controled Assesment\text file login\text file login\username.txt",true);
        StreamWriter pass_reg = new StreamWriter(@"E:\SSD\Controled Assesment\text file login\text file login\password.txt",true);

        user_reg.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
        user_reg.Close();
        pass_reg.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
        pass_reg.Close();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    string user = "";
    int txt_position = 0;
    private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader user_login = new StreamReader(@"E:\SSD\Controled Assesment\text file login\text file login\username.txt", true);
        StreamReader pass_login = new StreamReader(@"E:\SSD\Controled Assesment\text file login\text file login\password.txt", true);

        do
        {
            user = user_login.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
            txt_position++;
        } while (user_login.Peek() != -1);

        string pass = File.ReadLines(@"E:\SSD\Controled Assesment\text file login\text file login\password.txt").Skip(txt_position).Take(1).First();

        if ((pass == textBox2.Text) && (user == textBox1.Text))
        {
            quiz_details form2 = new quiz_details();

            form2.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            // message box
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Well I've been able to write new lines into the text file and get to login (i think) i havent got to check as i keep getting this error
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: Sequence contains no elements"

I've been trying to read one textfile and find the username first and then stop when it does and save the position so i can input that into the skip to skip straight to that line on the other text file so as to find the corresponding password.

Is there any way to make this work or am i just wasting my time with this method and im completely wrong. I apologies if I am. I want to learn by making the code myself and not just copy code and try to understand.

Comment: Well, it's a bit convoluted really.  Why store username and password in separate files?  Why this complicated skipping mechanism?  Just put them in the same file and write it out like "username:password" then you just read one line, then split on the colon (you have to make sure colon is not allowed in the password)

Comment: I didnt know about the colon thanks. And yeah i know its terribly inefficient and convoluted sorry.

Comment: Well done on a well-written question with a good code sample. But to be honest, the approach you have taken is so fundamentally erroneous I find this question difficult to answer.

Comment: Yeah i'll ask again after if i use Erik's advice and use "username:password" so i can just split on the colon and try it and still get an error

Comment: The downvote on this question was unnecessary. OP stated he was new to coding, so the bad design should be expected. Outside of that, at least there was some real effort by the OP to get to a solution. Sorry but this is one of the things that bugs me with SO and how new users are treated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming from the Skip().Take().First() statement (or rather from which values you have supplied it)

by splitting up your program a bit more, you could make it a lot more programmer friendly afterwards (don't look at the code for 6 months and then check it again :))

A way to organize such stuff a bit better, would be in the following way (i wrote it as a console program, so you could just copy paste it inside a new consoleproject and it should work (and show the logic to you))

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace RegisterUsers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void AppendToFile(string file, string value)
        {
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(value);
            }
        }

        static void Register(string userFile, string passwordFile, string userName, string password)
        {
            AppendToFile(userFile, userName);
            AppendToFile(passwordFile, password);
        }

        static string[] GetLines(string file)
        {
            string[] result = null;
            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            }
            return result;
        }

        static bool TryLogin(string userFile, string passwordFile, string username, string password)
        {
            string[] userArray = GetLines(userFile);
            int index = -1, length = userArray.Length;
            for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
            {
                if (string.Equals(userArray[x], username))
                {
                    index = x;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (index < 0)
            {
                // no username found that matches your requirement
                return false;
            }
            string[] passArray = GetLines(passwordFile);
            if (index > passArray.Length)
            {
                // inconsistency, shouldn't happen...
                return false;
            }
            return string.Equals(passArray[index], password);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // keep the filenames, don't have to repeat them all the time
            string usernameFile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "UserFile.txt");
            string passwordFile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "PassFile.txt");

            // register 2 users, one with falsely typed testUser2 as tesetUser2
            Register(usernameFile, passwordFile, "testUser1", "password1");
            Register(usernameFile, passwordFile, "tesetUser2", "password15");

            // try to login with the testUser1 should work
            if (TryLogin(usernameFile, passwordFile, "testUser1", "password1"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Login succesfull");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Login failed!");
            }

            // try to login with testUser2 shouldn't work (now correctly typed)
            if (TryLogin(usernameFile, passwordFile, "testUser2", "password15"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Login succesfull");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Login failed!");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, ive been working on this for hours and im not too good and i cant thank you enough

Comment: believe it or not splitting up parts of your program will become second nature to you if you continue programming, it helps making you write less code, or at least, making sure that if you have an error, the error can be traced back to a single point, instead of repeating the error by copy pasting code pieces ;)

Answer (score 2):

So you have a file with usernames and a file with passwords that match those usernames. When the user clicks the `Login` button, you're trying to lookup the username they entered from the file, find the line that username is at, and then lookup the corresponding password in the password file.

Let's forget for a moment that this is a pretty awful way to handle security, and just deal with trying to get the code to work for instructive purposes.

The first task is to get the line of the matching username. I would write a method to do just that, something like this:

```
private int GetUsernameIndex(string username)
{
    //Use a using statement so we don't leave the username.txt file
    //open after we're done reading from it, using will call Dispose for you
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\temp\username.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        var index = 0;

        //when sr.ReadLine == null, we've reached the end of the file
        while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if(string.Equals(line, username))
                return index;
            index++;
        }

        //Return -1 if username not found
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This method will return the index of the user, or -1 if the user is not found. The next method we need to write is the method to get the password, which could look like this:

```
private string GetPassword(int index)
{
    //Don't bother to search a negative index
    if(index < 0) return string.Empty;

    //Find the line matching the index and return the value there
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\temp\password.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        var currentLine = 0;
        while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if(index == currentLine)
                return line;
            currentLine++;
        }

        //Return string.Empty if line not found
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Finally, we'll write a method to put these two together and validate a username and password:

```
private bool IsUsernameAndPasswordValid(string username, string password)
{
    var index = GetUsernameIndex(username);
    var storedPassword = GetPassword(index);

    //If storedPassword is empty, then return false
    //If password and storedPassword do not match, then return false
    //Otherwise, the password is valid for this user
    return storedPassword != string.Empty && password == storedPassword; 
}
```

Hopefully this will help give you some of the basics for file I/O. Again, your design is far from ideal, but IMO it helps to know how to write that code if you wanted to.

Comment: Thanks so much, security isnt a priority at all its just to use a text file but for some reason im made to use it for a login and im not able to connect a database.